# AngularUI Calendar get events object to scope after fetching

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, angular-ui

I am using [UI-Calendar](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/), I am getting events from database with a built-in GET request:

HTML

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" calendar="calendar"
     id="calendar" ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar">
</div>
```

Controller

```
App.controller('calendarController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$routeParams', 'uiCalendarConfig', function($scope, $http, $location, $routeParams, uiCalendarConfig) {


  $scope.eventSources = [{
    url: window.SRMDATA.URL + "/api/events",
    currentTimezone: 'Europe/Istanbul',
  }];

  $scope.uiConfig = {
    calendar:{
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
      },
    }
  };


}]);
```

I am looking for a way to share the events object to the $scope because I need some data from them. I couldn't find a way to know when the previous `eventSources` GET request is done successfully or how do I get the events object from it.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Beware of `angular-ui-calendar`, it has two hundred open issues and has not been updated in two years. While it claims to play nicely with `ng-model`, the directive bypasses the ngModelController and does not play nicely with the form controller.

Comment: I don't know any alternatives, I really need a smart one.